# Subtracting seconds from Timestamp

Tags: math, timestamp, subtraction, divide

I have a column that is a timestamp (DateTime) and a column (TalkTime) that is the number of seconds an interaction lasted. I need to be able to subtract the number of seconds of the interaction from the timestamp in order to get the time the interaction started. The DateTime is when the interaction ended.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvEAx.png)

sel
(D.TALKTIME/60)- D.Datetime